# How to update values from rows on a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, heuristics

I have a matrix: 6 rows x 18 columns
and I want to ask the user which row he wants to change to 0 and make it happen, but if he inputs 0 it just exits the program

```
row = input('Input 0 to exit\n\n Row to eliminate:', 's');
if row ~= 0
    M(row,:) = 0;
    disp(M)
end
```

I want to to change the whole input row to 0, but it somehow creates 44 more rows below the original matrix (all 0) and doesn't change the first 6 rows(original matrix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`row` is a char vector, not a number. For example if you type “4”, the variable contains the character 4, which has a numeric value of 52 (ASCII code). Using that to index will create a row #52 and fill it with zeros. To make that row it needed to make the intermediate rows as well, whose values default to 0.

To solve the problem, remove the `'s'` from the call to `input`. This will cause the return value to be interpreted as a MATLAB expression, rather than directly returning the entered text as a char vector.

However, if there is a chance that your program is used by a malicious user or a stupid user, this solution is dangerous (as indicated by [@Luis Mendo in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54384694/how-to-update-values-from-rows-on-a-matrix/54384757?noredirect=1#comment95586575_54384757)) because it evaluates whatever the user types, which means the user can e.g. type a command that wipes your hard drive.

A safer solution is to use `str2double` to convert the char array output of `input` to a number that you can use to index.

Comment: Or maybe use the safer `row = str2double(input('...', 's'));`. `input` without `'s'` evaluates whatever the user types as code, which is dangerous

Comment: @Luis: Right you are! I’ve updated the answer with your suggestion.